# Sudo aptitude search produces bus error

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude, segmentation-fault

I've got a strange aptitude error while performing search:

```
$ sudo aptitude search pcre
Bus error
$ sudo aptitude search libpcre
Bus error
$ sudo aptitude autoclean 
Bus errorackage lists... 0%
```

What is wrong here? How do I fix this?

`aptitude update` does not work either - it ends up with the same bus error

*UPDATE*: Accordingly to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212466/what-is-a-bus-error the error refers to segfault, but still, how do I fix it?

Comment: does any other sudo command works?

Comment: yep. `sudo su -` is ok, `sudo cp` too

Comment: for me the partition containing `/var/cache` was simply full https://askubuntu.com/a/915520/493379

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/192567) suggestion by Michael Vogt on Launchpad:

> Could you please try to remove /var/cache/apt/*.bin ? And see if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

This can be Solved by the following Commands.

I have installed LUbuntu on my old desktop and I got an issue when I tried to download a

UNRAR file.

Error Occurred as

pavan_surya@lakshmi-SuryaNarayanaMurthy:~$ sudo apt-get install unrar

[sudo] password for pavan_surya:

Bus errorackage lists... 0%

then i tried to do in the following way

sudo fuser -vvv /var/lib/dpkg/lock

sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

sudo cp -arf /var/lib/dpkg /var/lib/dpkg.backup

sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status

sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists

sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin

sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists

sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial

LANG=C;sudo apt-get clean

LANG=C;sudo apt-get autoclean

LANG=C;sudo apt-get --purge autoremove

LANG=C;sudo apt-get update -o APT::Cache-Limit=25165824

sudo dpkg --clear-avail

sudo dpkg --configure -a

LANG=C;sudo apt-get -f install

LANG=C;sudo apt-get --fix-missing install

and after that again i tried to download the UNrar file

i got error as

pavan_surya@lakshmi-SuryaNarayanaMurthy:~$ sudo apt install rar

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package rar

so then i got an idea to update my packages and

LANG=C;sudo apt-get update -o APT::Cache-Limit=25165824 && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

**And finally Succeded with the installation**

pavan_surya@lakshmi-SuryaNarayanaMurthy:~$ sudo apt install rar

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Suggested packages:
  unrar
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  rar

0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 53 not upgraded.

Need to get 304 kB of archives.

After this operation, 829 kB of additional disk space will be used.

Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse i386 rar i386 2:5.5.0-1 [304 kB]

Fetched 304 kB in 2s (142 kB/s)

Selecting previously unselected package rar.
(Reading database ... 164268 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack .../rar_2%3a5.5.0-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking rar (2:5.5.0-1) ...

Setting up rar (2:5.5.0-1) ...

Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...

Thanks for the patience and if you found useful upvote and comment if you found  mistake comment i will rectify

Comment: Plese fix the formatting of your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the commands Pavan vadrevu posted. It worked for me.

I was trying to download libctl using 
`$ sudo apt-get install ...` but this was met with 
`Bus errorackage lists... 0%`.

After following his entire process, despite a few lines of command resulting in error messages on my computer (which were promptly ignored and the next command was then proceeded with), the `$ sudo apt-get` command worked and the libctl library installed with the error resolved.

So after resolving this error via this method, and trying the `sudo aptitude update` (or `sudo apt-get update`) command you mentioned you tried, I do not encounter the `Bus errorackage lists... 0%` error. Similarly, `sudo aptitude search pcre` or `$ sudo apt-cache search pcre` worked. Lastly, `sudo aptitude autoclean` (or `$ sudo apt-get autoclean`) cleaned my redundant packages out just fine.

Hope this helps anyone who was facing the same error.